# What is the best way of formatting text in this Flutter example?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a card that I tap to toggle DND on or off. On the card, at the moment, I have a string of text that says either "DND ON" or "DND OFF". What I am trying to achieve is to add, below "DND ON", in smaller fontsize and in italics: "Alarms, Media, Touch Sounds".

My bare bones code:

```
            Card(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 175, 80),
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                pressed = !pressed;
              });
              pressed ? _dndOn() : _dndOff();
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                pressed ? ('DND ON') : ('DND OFF'),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

What I have tried: I have tried defining my string in RichText, using TextTheme, and creating a column of text with various styles. Every time I get an error such as "type 'Column' is not a subtype of type 'String'" or "type 'RichText' is not a subtype of type 'String' etc.

Would you have any ideas as to how I could achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a [column widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) as the text property of the Text widget. You need to use it in a way where you define the list of children to hold, in this case, the list of Text widgets.

```
Card(
  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 76, 175, 80),
  elevation: 5.0,
  child: InkWell(
    splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        pressed = !pressed;
      });
      pressed ? _dndOn() : _dndOff();
    },
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            pressed ? 'DND ON' : 'DND OFF',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Alarms, Media, Touch Sounds',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```